# REGEX Split string into List using keyword

Tags: c#, regex, list, split

I have the string as below and i need to split the string into list

```
string s = "Welcome to the Center

Batch #1 
English
Description about the course

Batch #2
Science
Description about the course

Batch #3
Social 
Description about the course "
```

I want to split the string using `"Batch"` keyword and the output should look like below. How to split using regex ?

```
myList[0]="Batch #1 
English
Description about the course"

myList[1]="Batch #2
Science
Description about the course"

myList[2]="Batch #3 
Social
Description about the course"
```

Comment: What did you try? See [Should "Give me a regex that does X" questions be closed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285733/should-give-me-a-regex-that-does-x-questions-be-closed)

Answer (score 2):

You can do try the below:-

```
List<string> strList = Regex.Split(str, "Batch").Skip(1).ToList();
```

Comment: I'm missing the word 'Batch' in the list after split

Comment: Yes, Appending "Batch" keyword with every item would work.

Comment: List<string> strList = Regex.Split(str, "Batch").Skip(1).Select(x => "Batch" + x).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

You should use `.*?`

```
Batch.*?course
```

or

```
Batch.*?.\n.*\n.*
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](https://regexr.com/4obh2)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regular expressions, just split the string on two consecutive newline characters (`\r\n\r\n` sequence to be precise):

```
  string s = @"Welcome to the Center

  Batch #1 
  English
  Description about the course

  Batch #2
  Science
  Description about the course

  Batch #3
  Social
  Description about the course ";

  var splitted = s.Split(new string[] { "\r\n\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
  splitted.RemoveAt(0);
```